# If $A\in\mathfrak{M}$, then there exist Borel sets $F$ and $G$ such that $F\subset A\subset G$, and $\mu(G-A)=\mu(A-F)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-sets, borel-measures

The problem arises from Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:
[image]

Here is (b):
[image]

Now, the highlighted texts seem innocent enough; but I failed to prove it rigorously, i.e., to explicitly show the existence of $F$ and $G$. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how (d) follows from (b) or how we know (b) is true?

Comment: @pleasantpheasant How (d) follows from (b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use (b), we take a sequence of open sets $A \subset G_{k}$ and a sequence of closed sets $F_{k}\subset A$ such that $\mu(G_{k}-F_{k})<\frac{1}{k}$ and we define $G=\bigcap_{k}G_{k}$ and $F=\bigcup_{k}F_{k}$ and these are the desired sets.